# Fetch Low accuracy GPS location when High accuracy is enabled

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, battery

Is it possible to fetch location with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` or `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER` even when GPS is of `HIGH_ACCURACY` using Google Play Services lib?

Scenario here is I want to use location with high accuracy for some cases in my app, but for some cases, low accuracy mode is enough. So to save battery for later cases, I want to use low accuracy mode.

Comment: low accuracy will return network location (wifi + cellular)! You can't request gps fix with custom accuracy!

Answer (score 0):

You could configure two `LocationRequests`. One with `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` and one with `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` or `PRIORITY_LOW_POWER`. Request location updates for the high accuracy request only when needed and remove the location request when you don't need it anymore. You'd probably have to wait a bit until a GPS fix is established and the desired accuracy is reached.

Comment: @Emauel : In the question it is asked that if GPS is currently with PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, when requesting location updates with PRIORITY_LOW_POWER will GPS return location with HIGH OR LOW accuracy?

Comment: @aagam94 : In the second paragraph he describes the scenario. He needs high accuracy only sometimes. For the rest of the time he only wants low accuracy to save battery power. He cannot have both with only one LocationRequest.